# Facebook Graph Api | page follower count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to take the number of followers and likes of an public page. I try this request
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/138432502881936?fields=engagement,fan_count&access_token=access_token

Then return result:`{
  "engagement": {
    "count": 9894383,
    "social_sentence": "9.8M people like this."
  },
  "fan_count": 9894383,
  "id": "138432502881936"
}`

Page's likes count changes instantly but I can not get followers. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: No, number of followers is not available via API.

Comment: also, followers are for user profiles, not pages

Comment: Pages also have followers count. People can follow a page without liking it.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by using a HTTP request, not using the API. I just request the page www.facebook.com/whatever_name_of_the_page, no need to be logged in, and then check for a match of 'XXX people follow this' using regular expressions. I tested with python requests package and worked just fine.

Comment: this may be useful but does not answer the question. please post an example and explain your answer